# Easiest setup of FTP server with virtual users on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I want an FTPd running on my server, with an easy way to setup users/directories. I don't need MySQL, anon access, local users etc. Preferably the users setup would be a plain file with something like

```
username 1        password hash         /root/dir
username 2        password hash         /root/dir
username 3        password hash         /root/dir
```

What's the fastest easiest way to setup FTPd with virtual users?

Answer (score 1):

ProFTPd offers such thing as you request:

```
ProFTPD allows for the definition of "virtual" users: users who do not have accounts on
the host machine, whose account information is defined in other sources. The passwords for
these users are then specific only to FTP access, and thus do not expose shell access
(ssh, hopefully) to unauthorized users. These alternative account information sources
include SQL tables (via mod_sql), LDAP servers (via mod_ldap), CDB files (via
mod_auth_cdb), and other system files (via the AuthUserFile and AuthGroupFile
configuration directives). The proftpd server can be configured to use multiple account
information sources simultaneously as well, allowing for flexible support of a range of
environments.
```

I personally was using mod_sql plugin fro ProFTPd to avoid using OS users for FTP access. Here you can find more information if it will suits you this solution:

[ProFTPd Authentication virtual](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Authentication.html#virtual)

[ProFTPd AuthFiles](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/AuthFiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/) article. It contains information to setup VSFTPD with virtual users. 
A google search on "+linux +ftp +virtual users" also gives a lot of options you can try out.

Comment: "[..] enabled local access which we need for virtual users" :-( I would really prefer not to have local access enabled